# Are there Vim's explicit "native functions"?

Tags: function, vim, mapping, call

I'm trying not to get messed up in remapping keys with Vim, and it's getting better now I've been reading documentation for half a day. @_@

Still, I am very happy when I can type something pretty straightforward like this in my `.vimrc` :

```
map <onekey> <plug>OneExplicitFunctionalityName
```

or :

```
noremap <onekey> :call OneExplicitFunctionalityName()<CR>
```

And I then wonder: do the basic Vim's actions have explicit *names* we could call like these above? Is there a way to replace something like

```
nnoremap > ;
```

by something like

```
nnoremap > :call MoveToTheNextFSearchResult()<CR>
```

?

Are there such things like `MoveCursorLeft()`, `DeleteLine()`, `GetWordLimits()` etc?

The idea, of course, is to play around then with these "native motions"..

Comment: Actually for your <plug> mappings, you *can't* use "noremap", you need to use "map", because these mappings rely on executing the <plug>... text as a mapping in turn.

Comment: Oh, that's a nasty one, cheers! ^ ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Vimscript functions for built-in commands; you can include them in a (`:noremap`) mapping, or explicitly invoke them via `:normal!`.

> ```
> nmap > ;
> ```

When you remap built-in commands, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion. Your above mapping would do strange things should you remap `;` as well.

Comment: Okay, let's try without it then. Thanks! I did know for the `*noremap` but didn't wan't to put too much: I'll change it. Unfortunately, your command doesn't seem to work in my `.vimrc` and I still can't figure out why..

Comment: For the mapping, that would be `:nnoremap > ;`. With `:normal!`, keep in mind that _everything_ after it is treated as normal-mode commands, unless you wrap it in `:execute`.

Comment: Still didn't work, but wait.. got it! The default `;` behavior was actually hidden by the [`extended-ft.vim`](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-extended-ft) plugin (great!): I had it working at last using the `<Plug>ExtendedFtOperationModeRepeatSearchForward`, the `<Plug>ExtendedFtVisualModeRepeatSearchForward` and the `<Plug>ExtendedFtRepeatSearchForward` mappings.